# Aggregation by date in composed _id Morphia

Tags: java, aggregation-framework, morphia

I need to reproduce an aggregation like this in Morphia

```
db.getCollection('forecasting').aggregate(
[
    {
        $match:{
            ....
            }
    },
    {
        $group: {
                    _id:{id:"$id", date:"$date", hour:{$hour:"$date"}},
                    property1: {$sum:"$property1"},
                    property2: {$sum:"$property2"}
            }
    }
])
```

But I can't seem to reproduce it in Morphia, particulary the `hour:{$hour:"$date"}` group.
If I make a projection for that field, this is what's generated: `"hour" : "$date"`, but I need to generate the `$hour` operator.

```
 Group idGroup = Group.grouping("_id",
                                   Projection.projection(ID_FIELD, ID_FIELD),
                                   Projection.projection(DATE_FIELD, DATE_FIELD),
                                   Projection.projection("hour", DATE_FIELD);

mongoDataStore.createAggregation(XXX.class)                                                                
              .match(query)                                                                
              .group(idGroup);
```

If I add the date group as another group like:

```
mongoDataStore.createAggregation(XXX.class)
              .match(query)
              .group(idGroup,dateGroup)
```

I get the following error:

> Command failed with error 40234 (Location40234): 'The field '$hour' must be an accumulator object' on server

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this question [Aggregation by date in Morphia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251256/aggregation-by-date-in-morphia)

You have to use the `Group.id` method that accepts multiple `Groups`, so that you can use an `Accumulator` in order to apply the `$hour` operator